# Dict of lists to df

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dict of lists like so:

```
    {291840: ['http://www.rollanet.org', 'http://www.rollanet.org'], 
     291841: ['http://www.superpages.com', 'http://www.superpages.com], 
     291848: ['http://www.drscore.com/App/ScoreDr', 'http://www.drscore.com'],...etc }
```

I want to convert it to a two column dataframe, one for the `subj_id` and the other for the corresponding list. Each row will be a key of the dict and the column be the value(list) using `from_dict` with orient set to index. According to documentation: "orient: if the keys should be rows, pass ‘index’."

```
names = ['subj_id', 'URLs']

dfDict = pd.DataFrame(columns = names)
dfDict.from_dict(listDict, orient = 'index')
```

Instead I get a dataframe that has each element of the lists as a column. I only want two columns. One for the `subj_ID` and the other for the lists of URLs associated with `subj_ID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
listDict = {291840: ['http://www.rollanet.org', 'http://www.rollanet.org'], 
     291841: ['http://www.superpages.com', 'http://www.superpages.com'], 
     291848: ['http://www.drscore.com/App/ScoreDr', 'http://www.drscore.com']}

names = ['subj_id', 'URLs']

df = pd.DataFrame(listDict).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=0).reset_index()
df.columns = names
print (df)
   subj_id                                URLs
0   291840             http://www.rollanet.org
1   291841           http://www.superpages.com
2   291848  http://www.drscore.com/App/ScoreDr
3   291840             http://www.rollanet.org
4   291841           http://www.superpages.com
5   291848              http://www.drscore.com
```

Old answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(listDict, orient='index').stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
```

If need list in column `URLs` use `list comprehensions`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subj_id': pd.Series([k for k,v in listDict.items()]),
                   'URLs': pd.Series([v for k,v in listDict.items()])}, columns = names)
print (df)
   subj_id                                               URLs
0   291840  [http://www.rollanet.org, http://www.rollanet....
1   291841  [http://www.superpages.com, http://www.superpa...
2   291848  [http://www.drscore.com/App/ScoreDr, http://ww...
```

Comment: In my case, each URL list has varying sizes. So with your code i got the error "ValueError: arrays must all be same length"

Comment: jezreals previous (deleted) answer works for varying sizes:
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(listDict, orient='index').stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)

Comment: @Skirrebattie - Thank you, I add old answer

Answer (score 4):

since I'm too late to give jezrael's answer, here's an interesting way to do it:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(v, [k] * len(v)) for k, v in listDict.items()]) \
    .rename_axis('subj_id').reset_index(name='urls')
```

[image]

Comment: that is a potential way to do it, but for my purposes I want to keep each URL list together for its respective subj_id